# Why do I get a negative value when I try to read an array in descending order in java?

Tags: java, binary-search

I am trying to calculate the targeted gpa in both descending and ascending arrays, via a binary search of the file path written from command line, in the Java programming language.

My main Java files are the codes I wrote below.
The Student Java version is a separate file. The Student class and readcsv version are defined there.

When I calculate ascending sorted arrays, it calculates correctly,
but in descending sorted arrays it returns a negative value.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String path = args[0];
        Student[] Stdnt= Student.readCSV(path).clone();
        double[] GpaArray= new double[Stdnt.length];

        for(int i=0 ; i<Ogrenciler.length;i++){
            GpaArray[i] = Stdnt[i].getGPA();
        }
        int sayi = countOccurrences(GpaArray, 3.02);
        System.out.println(sayi);
    }

    public static int countOccurrences(double[] arr, double x) {
        int firstIndex;
        int lastIndex;

        if (arr[0] <= arr[arr.length - 1]) {
            // Increasing order
            firstIndex = findFirstOccurrence(arr, x, 0, arr.length - 1);
            lastIndex = findLastOccurrence(arr, x, 0, arr.length - 1);
        } else {
            // Decreasing order
            firstIndex = findFirstOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, 0, arr.length - 1);
            lastIndex = findLastOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, 0, arr.length - 1);
        }

        if (firstIndex == -1) {
            return 0;
        }

        return lastIndex - firstIndex + 1;
    }

    public static int findFirstOccurrence(double[] arr, double x, int left, int right) {
        if (left > right) {
            return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if ((mid == 0 || arr[mid - 1] < x) && arr[mid] == x) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] < x) {
            return findFirstOccurrence(arr, x, mid + 1, right);
        } else {
            return findFirstOccurrence(arr, x, left, mid - 1);
        }
    }

    public static int findLastOccurrence(double[] arr, double x, int left, int right) {
        if (left > right) {
            return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if ((mid == arr.length - 1 || arr[mid + 1] > x) && arr[mid] == x) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] > x) {
            return findLastOccurrence(arr, x, left, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return findLastOccurrence(arr, x, mid + 1, right);
        }
    }

    public static int findFirstOccurrenceDescending(double[] arr, double x, int left, int right) {
        if (left > right) {
            return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if ((mid == arr.length - 1 || arr[mid + 1] < x) && arr[mid] == x) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] < x) {
            return findFirstOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, left, mid - 1);
        } else {
            return findFirstOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, mid + 1, right);
        }
    }

    public static int findLastOccurrenceDescending(double[] arr, double x, int left, int right) {
        if (left > right) {
            return -1;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if ((mid == 0 || arr[mid - 1] < x) && arr[mid] == x) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] > x) {
            return findLastOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, mid + 1, right);
        } else {
            return findLastOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, left, mid - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public static int findLastOccurrenceDescending(double[] arr, double x, int left, int right) {
    if (left > right) {
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = (left + right) / 2;

    if ((mid == 0 || arr[mid - 1] > x) && arr[mid] == x) {
        return mid;
    } else if (arr[mid] > x) {
        return findLastOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, mid + 1, right);
    } else {
        return findLastOccurrenceDescending(arr, x, left, mid - 1);
    }
}
```